# How to sum 3 columns panda python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum the value of 3 columns for example `3 4 10`  I want as a result `17`  not `3410`! 
I did the following:

```
df2["OverAll"] = df2['reading'] + df2['math'] + df2['writing']
```

But it gives me the 3410 (put the 3 columns together!).

Please help!

Comment: It seems your colums consist of strings, not numbers. Show the code that generates the colums.

Answer (score 3):

That is because those columns are strings.

Try:

```
df['OverAll'] = df[['reading', 'math', 'writing']].astype(float).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert your columns to numeric dtypes first:

```
df[['reading','math','writing']] = \
    df[['reading','math','writing']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```